# excluding directories from aws cp

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

A current project directory on Mac machine, having some files and directories, needs to be copied over to aws s3 bucket but without some directories some of which are hidden.
I could not figure out from [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) how to do that, thus my guess is:

```
aws> s3 cp . s3://bucketName --recursive --exclude "how to put the list of directories to exclude here"?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon S3 doesn't really support directories. Rather, the name of directory (the "path") is pre-pended onto the name of the file.

So, imagine this structure:

```
docs
  + foo
  + bar
  + foobar
```

If you wish to copy then whole `docs` directory, but skip the `bar` directory, use this command from within the `docs` directory:

```
aws s3 cp . s3://mybucket --recursive --exclude 'bar/*'
```

This tells it to copy all files, **except** those that begin with `bar/`.

Answer (score 1):

From [s3's Use of Filters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters):

> Any number of these parameters can be passed to a command. You can do
>   this by providing an --exclude or --include argument multiple times,
>   e.g. --include "*.txt" --include "*.png". When there are multiple
>   filters, the rule is the filters that appear later in the command take
>   precedence over filters that appear earlier in the command.

So, just give the command an `--exclude` option for each directory you want to skip.