# Use the aws client to copy s3 files from a single directory only (non recursively)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-cli

Consider an aws bucket/key structure along these lines

```
 myBucket/dir1/file1
 myBucket/dir1/file2
 myBucket/dir1/dir2/dir2file1
 myBucket/dir1/dir2/dir2file2
```

When using:

```
 aws s3 cp  --recursive s3://myBucket/dir1/ .
```

Then we will copy down `dir2file[1,2]` along with `file[1,2]`.  How to only copy the latter files and not files under subdirectories ?

Responding to a comment:  . I am not interested in putting a `--exclude` for every subdirectory so this is not a duplicate of [excluding directories from aws cp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879330/excluding-directories-from-aws-cp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879330/excluding-directories-from-aws-cp

Comment: Just to make sure, I understood the question correctly. Let's say there are more files.
myBucket/dir1/dir3/dir2file1
myBucket/dir1/dir3/dir2file2

 do you want to copy these files also or only from dir2?

Comment: only files directly under `dir1` and not under subdirectories

Comment: @AbhishekGarg  This is *not* a duplicate of that question. I am not interested in putting a `--excludes` for *every* subdirectory

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. Thanks for clarifying. Added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, you want to make sure that the files present in current directories are copied but anything in child directories should not be copied. I think you can use something like that.

```
aws s3 cp s3://myBucket/dir1/ . --recursive --exclude "*/*"
```

Here we are excluding files which will have a path separator after "dir1".

Comment: Well you get precisely the opposite of what I was looking for ;)  But looks like we can simply invert the conditions and would "fly".  Can you make that change?  I'll upvote in the meantime

Comment: I am slightly embarrassed that I didn't understand the question correctly. Updated the answer.

Comment: does not copy anything ;(

Comment: I tried this 

aws s3 ls s3://mapbox-test.xxxx.com/ --recursive --profile nq  
2019-07-16 11:56:51     137191 dir1/abc.jpg
2019-07-10 14:32:52        831 index.html

aws s3 cp s3://mapbox-test.xxx.com/ . --recursive --exclude "\*/\*"
This was the output. 
download: s3://mapbox-test.xxx.com/index.html to ./index.html

Comment: The comment format is making it confusing. But basically, there were 2 files and with the command, it only copied the file in current directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude paths using the `--exclude` option, e.g.

```
aws s3 cp s3://myBucket/dir1/ . --recursive --exclude "dir1/dir2/*"
```

More options and examples can be found by using the aws cli help

```
aws s3 cp help
```

Comment: The asterisk is not expanded by the shell locally?

Comment: This does not meet the needs of the question .. I don't want to put an `--excludes` for _every_ subdirectory

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can control the recursion depth while copying files using `aws s3 cp`. Neither it is supported in `aws s3 ls`.

So, if you do not wish to use `--exclude` or `--include` options, I suggest you:

1. Use `aws s3 ls` command without `--recursive` option to list files directly under a directory, extract only the file names from the output and save the names to a file. Refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36813327/how-to-display-only-files-from-aws-s3-ls-command)
2. Then write a simple script to read the file names and for each execute `aws s3 cp`

Alternatively, you may use:

```
aws s3 cp s3://spaces/dir1/ .  --recursive --exclude "*/*"
```